# Can't install APK file on Samsung Galaxy- 'APK file incompatible', error code 1384

Tags: android, apk, galaxy-tab

I'm having trouble installing an APK file on my Samsung Galaxy running Android 4.4.4. I had previously had the app installed and working fine, but had to perform a factory reset on my phone and now only have the APK file. The app 'installs' using an APK installer, but when I try to open it it tells me the APK file is incompatible. I've looked for solutions online but they all seem to involve rooting the phone which I'd prefer to avoid (the phone on a contract and don't want to accidentally mess it up considering I don't actually own it). Does anyone know if there's a way to get around this without rooting the phone? Thanks.

Comment: Just throwing ideas out: (a) Had you updated you version of Android when this APK was "previously working"? and (b) Have you checked the APK has not got corrupted?

Comment: I never manually updated the version of Android, however I don't know if it was updated when I performed the factory reset. How would I go about checking whether or not the APK was corrupted?

Comment: Check against where you originally got it from?

Comment: I tried downloading and installing the most recent file from the same source, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there a more detailed error in the android log?

Comment: I don't know how to view the Android log without rooting the phone, sorry.